# What does "sur les chapeaux de roues" mean?

Tags: sens, expressions

Doing something or starting something "sur les chapeaux de roues".
What does it mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Sur les chapeaux de roues* = démarrer *à toute vitesse*, démarrer *très vite*, *très rapidement*.

Fait une référence littérale aux prises de virage des voitures à grande vitesse, historiquement.

Voir [une explication de l'origine](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sur_les_chapeaux_de_roues) sur le Wiktionnaire.